# Can not find the URL to download (Web scraping by using R)

Tags: r, web-scraping, download

I just want to use R to scrap the webpage and download the file automatically.

https://www.maklarstatistik.se/omrade/riket/stockholms-lan/stockholm/#/bostadsratter/arshistorik-prisutveckling

If you open this webpage and you can find buttom like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNSPb.png)

I checked the source code, check the element which corresponds to the download button
and try to find out the xlsx file name

but I cannot find anything.

I only found this, but it is not the file url.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8rlI.png)

I just wonder how I can find the download file URL.
or How I can simulate to generate the xlsx file just like I clicking the button by using R

Thank you so much!

Comment: You should have a look at the [R selenium](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2014/12/scraping-with-selenium/).

Comment: They are making it deliberately difficult to scrape their site as they have a paid API service: https://api.maklarstatistik.se/. RSelenium would bypass it though